# In Grails, is there a way to restrict the HTTP request method type (other than the allowedMethods map)?

Tags: java, grails

For example, if I have a `save()` method, how can I restrict the HTTP request method of this action?

Looking at the grails [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html), it looks like I can use this `static allowedMethods = [...]` block to restrict access. However, it looks quite a bit clunky because the list can grow quite big and it can get very messy.

Ideally, I would like to use annotations to describe the method. It could be something like this:

```
@POST
def save() {
    // save logic
}
```

This way I know all the information related to the `save()` method right there. Instead of scrolling up and potentially seeing a huge messy list.

I'd be happy to use an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own annotations and use filters/interceptors to check if request method corresponds the given annotation. You can find more details [here](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=80).